# SSRS String null check on MS CRM TwoOptionsetValue="True"

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, ssrs-expression

I want to concatenate 2 twooptionset values from MS CRM on true condition seperated by commas on a textbox and leave a blank if 2 twooptionset values are false.

I have writen an Expression in SSRS:

```
=iif(Len(Cstr(iif(Fields!aaValue.Value="True","aa,","") & iif(Fields!bbValue.Value="True","bb,","")))=0,"",
 Left((iif(Fields!aaValue.Value="True","aa,","") & iif(Fields!bbValue.Value="True","bb,","")),
 len(iif(Fields!aaValue.Value="True","aa,","") & iif(Fields!bbValue.Value="True","bb,","")) - 1
)
```

If either of 2 twooptionset values are true then it shows a text on textbox.
If Both twooptionset values are false then it shows #error on the textbox.

So how to check null string in SSRS?

Comment: IsNothing Didn't worked for me i tried earlier. If X = iif(Fields!aaValue.Value="True","aa,","") & iif(Fields!bbValue.Value="True","bb,","") Is there any difference between =IIF(len(x)=0,"",Left((x),iif(len(x)=0,0,len(x) - 1))) and =IIF(len(x)=0,"",Left((x),len(x) - 1)) Because =IIF(len(x)=0,"",Left((x),iif(len(x)=0,0,len(x) - 1))) worked for me and =IIF(len(x)=0,"",Left((x),len(x) - 1)) Didn't Worked for me

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `IsNothing` function. Remember, in SSRS these expressions are actually writte in the Visual Basic language.

However, the `IsNothing` function is not necessary at all. Just use the `CBool` conversion function. It can handle `Nothing` (null) values:

```
= (Iif(CBool(Fields!aaValue.Value), "aa,", "")
    & Iif(CBool(Fields!bbValue.Value), "bb,", "")).TrimEnd(",")
```

Comment: IsNothing Didn't worked for me i tried earlier.
If X = iif(Fields!aaValue.Value="True","aa,","") & iif(Fields!bbValue.Value="True","bb,","")

Is there any difference between 

=IIF(len(x)=0,"",Left((x),iif(len(x)=0,0,len(x) - 1)))

and

=IIF(len(x)=0,"",Left((x),len(x) - 1))


Because =IIF(len(x)=0,"",Left((x),iif(len(x)=0,0,len(x) - 1))) worked for me 
and =IIF(len(x)=0,"",Left((x),len(x) - 1))  Didn't Worked for me